# Trigger an alert when a new element is added to the array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In this code, it displays (Test1, Test2, Test3) and sends an alert [Test1, Test2, Test3].

When I activate the 'show' boxes, it adds other elements (Test4, Test5, Test6) to the new_arr_txt array.

Do you know how to receive a new alert each time a new element is added to the new_arr_txt array?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Alert", overlay=true)
import HeWhoMustNotBeNamed/RecursiveAlerts/2 as f

var tbl = table.new(position=position.top_right, columns=7, rows=41, border_width=3, frame_width=1)

show01 = input(true)
show02 = input(false)
show03 = input(true)
show04 = input(false)
show05 = input(true)
show06 = input(false)
show07 = input(false)
show08 = input(false)
show09 = input(false)
show10 = input(false)
show11 = input(false)
show12 = input(false)

arr_show = array.from(show01, show02, show03, show04, show05, show06, show07, show08, show09, show10, show11, show12)
arr_txt  = array.from('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6')
new_arr_txt  = array.new_string(0)


for i = 0 to array.size(arr_show) - 1 by 2
    if array.get(arr_show, i) or array.get(arr_show, i + 1)
        array.push(new_arr_txt, array.get(arr_txt, i/2))


if barstate.isrealtime
    for i = 0 to array.size(new_arr_txt) -1
        table.cell(tbl, 0, i, text=array.get(arr_txt, i), text_size=size.large, bgcolor=color.new(color.gray, 90), text_color=color.gray)
        alert(str.tostring(new_arr_txt), alert.freq_all)
```